# iSeries ILE-Cobol can't compile

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

I tried to compile (CRTBNDCBL) the example from "IBM Rational Development Studio for i - ILE Cobol Programmer's Guide", V7.2, Page 368-371
If the source type is just CBL everything works fine.
If I change the source type to CBLLE, the programm object can't be created.
I get QPJOBLOG, QPSRVDMP and QPDSPJOB spool files.
The job log tells me: 
MCH4229 ... invalid directory entry, Reason Code 13  (translated from german)
CPF93B6 ... problem protocol updated (translated too)

Main Problem is the MCH4229.

CRTCBLMOD works neither with a CBLLE source.

What's wrong ?

Any ideas/solution ?

Thank you in advance!
*Whole Msg :*
`MCH4229    Abbruch                 40   11.01.24  14:55:33,033791  VOXERROR                 002738   QBNCRTMD    QSYS     Zielmodul . . . . . . . . . :   QBNCRTMD                                             Zielprozedur  . . . . . . . :   main_module                                          Anweisung . . . . . . . . . :   1361                                                 Nachricht . . . :   Verzeichniseintrag ungültig.                                     Ursache  . . . . :  Das Objekt wurde nicht erstellt, da das Verzeichnis einen        ungültigen Eintrag enthält. Fehlerbeseitigung:  Im Umwandlungsprogramm             besteht ein Problem. Dieses Problem dem Lieferanten des Umwandlungsprogramms       melden. Technische Beschreibung . . . . . . . :  Ursachencode: 13.  Der            Index des ungültigen Verzeichniseintrags ist 133, der Verzeichniseintrag ist       X'050400010000006700000000000000000000002D000000007200900000000000', und die       relative Adresse für den Verzeichniseintrag ist 4276 Byte.  Die                    LIC-Protokollanmerkungs-ID ist 01000480.`

Answer (score 0):

MCHxxxx messages are usually indicative of something wrong in the OS; thus worth calling IBM about.

What version of IBM i are your running?  Are you current on PTFs?

I did find a PTF that references [ILE COBOL and MCH4229](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/SE53465).

But it was for 7.1.

Comment: V7R3M0 , which PTF status do you want to know? I'm not that much into operating and i'm just since 2 month here :-)

Comment: doesn't look like an answer, so I suggest to move that to a comment on the original question

Comment: @SimonSobisch the answer for an OS issue on a commercial midrange system, particularly the IBM i whose hardware and OS is provided by IBM, is to call the vendor; I've added that explicitly.

Comment: ... that's still no answer per Stackoverflows Q+A style, but a comment; the answer (which may be provided by IBM) should then be added as answer (likely as community-based), no?

Comment: Interesting problem - I have no solution, only observations:

I compiled the same example on pub400 (V7R5). It compiled as CBLLE successfully, also with TGTRLS(V7R3M0) (earliest I could specify on that machine). 

Your MCH4229 is coming from the translator. The compiler generates MI code, which the translator then translates into actual machine code. The translator is common to all programming languages on IBM i.

Simon Coulter had this with an RPG (!) program in 2008, but no further comment: https://archive.midrange.com/rpg400-l/200801/msg00506.html

Possibly quietly fixed by IBM...?

Comment: Update: On my V7R2 System, it also compiles fine as CBLLE.